# Find documents based on referenced ID in MongoDB & PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, nosql

i've got referenced Users collection object in my MongoDB Items collection. Random Item document looks like this:
*ps: to clarify, i really dont want to embed Items into Users collection.*
`Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoId Object
                (
                    [$id] => 4d3c589378be56a008000000
                )
            [modified] => 1295800467
            [order] => 1
            [title] => MyFirstItem
            [user] => Array
                (
                    [$ref] => users
                    [$id] => MongoId Object
                        (
                            [$id] => 4d3c55e7a130717c09000012
                        )
                )
        )`

So i need to find only items, which are assigned to the specific user. Find this question of my problem, but the solution didnt work for me.
[MongoDB-PHP: JOIN-like query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674358/mongodb-php-join-like-query)

Here is snippet of my code, givin' me no results at all.
`$user = $db->users->findOne(array("_id" => new MongoID("4d3c55e7a130717c09000012")));
$items = $db->items->find(array("user" => array('$id' => $user["_id"])));`
What is the correct way to finding that data? Should i instead put an user_id as a MongoID without reference?

Spent all my day with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$items = $db->items->find(array("user.$id" => $user["_id"]));
```